# Typegoose Mongoose Error - Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am facing issue with model registration and I have explained the code over here.

https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/633

Can anybody please check and share the thoughts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.